Tools or software for calculations in Quantum Affine Algebras
I am curious if there's a tool/math software to help with calculations in Quantum Affine Algebras, specially using the Drinfeld realization, i.e. the realization in Theorem 4.7 of Beck. For example I would like to calculate expressions of the form
$$[x_{i,r}^+x_{j,s}^+ , x_{k,t}^-x_{l,u}^-]$$
for specific $i,j,k,l,r,s,t,u$.
Thank you very much in advance!
